# How the Output Variable is working without Declaring it

Tags: sql-server

I have this query - can anyone please tell how `@retvalOUT` is working without defining it?

```
DECLARE @retval int   
DECLARE @sSQL nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

DECLARE @tablename nvarchar(50)  
SELECT @tablename = N'products'  

SELECT @sSQL = N'SELECT @retvalOUT = MAX(ID) 
                 FROM ' + @tablename;  
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@retvalOUT int OUTPUT';

EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL, @ParmDefinition, @retvalOUT = @retval OUTPUT;

SELECT @retval;
```

I read the links but not have the answer properly.

My question like where `@retvalOUT` is getting declared.

Please explain these lines:

```
SELECT @sSQL = N'SELECT @retvalOUT = MAX(ID) FROM ' + @tablename;  
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@retvalOUT int OUTPUT';
```

Comment: You did defined `@retvalOUT` in `@ParmDefinition` If not you will get error something like `Must declare the variable "@retvalOUT"`

Comment: Sorry I am new Bie to this type of code.. So We used @retvalOUT before defining it in line SELECT '@sSQL' = N'SELECT '@retvalOUT = MAX(ID) 
                 FROM ' + @tablename; and then we defined it.. it worked like that? where is datatype of this variable...

Comment: It's not **used** in that first line - that first line **just DEFINES** the SQL statement to be executed (it could just as well use `SET` instead of `SELECT`) - it's not doing anything else or "using" that parameter. Only with the `sp_executesql` call are the SQL statement, and the defined `OUT` parameter, really "used" ...

Comment: **IMPORTANT** this dynamic query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Since identifiers can't be parameterized, you need to white-list them to be sure it doesn't contain anything that can hurt your system, from malicious SQL code to a misspelled table name that will throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sp_executesql** is a stored procedure. Every procedure can have 0-many parameters passed. SQL Server allows three ways of passing parameters:

- Raw: EXEC someprocedure 5, @somevariable, 'test'
- Parameter name = value: EXEC someprocedure @paramName1 = 5, @paramName2 = @somevariable, @paramName3 = 'test'
- Mixed. EXEC someprocedure 5, @somevariable, @param3 = 'test'

Mixed is a bit special, since as soon as you start declaring parameters, you can't "go back" to raw value, so this is not allowed:

```sql
EXEC someprocedure @param1 = 1, @param2 = 10, 'test' -- Not allowed!
```

Parameters can be IN (the standard) or INOUT (meaning you can get the value back). INOUT parameters need a variable and an OUTPUT marker:

Raw version:

```sql
DECLARE @out INT
EXEC someprocedure 5, 10, @out OUTPUT
```

Name=value version:

```sql
DECLARE @out INT
EXEC someprocedure 5, 10, @paramOutput = @out OUTPUT
```

Note that every procedure decides the names it accepts. But the parameter value variables doesn't have to match the parameter name.

**sp_executesql** is a special procedure that allows executing dynamic SQL and bind parameters, thus allowing safe parameterization.

The procedure has a variable parameter structure.
The parameters to it looks like this:

```
parameter 1: @statement NVARCHAR(MAX)
parameter 2: @params NVARCHAR(MAX)
dynamic parameters 3,4,5,6...
```

1. First parameter is the SQL it should execute
2. Second parameter is declared list of parameters the SQL should accept
3. Third parameter etc is the actual parameters you want to pass to your SQL code.

Your SQL have one parameter called @retvalOUT. You declare it by @retvalOUT int OUTPUT, meaning it's an integer inout parameter.

```sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL, @ParmDefinition, @retvalOUT = @retval OUTPUT;
```

This code passes the value of the @retvalOUT parameter inside the @retval variable, and outputs it there as well.

You could've also shorted the code to:

```sql
SELECT @sSQL = N'SELECT @retvalOUT = MAX(ID) 
                 FROM ' + @tablename;  

EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL, N'@retvalOUT int OUTPUT', @retvalOUT = @retval OUTPUT;
```

or even:

```sql
SELECT @sSQL = N'SELECT @retvalOUT = MAX(ID) 
                 FROM ' + @tablename;  

EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL, N'@retvalOUT int OUTPUT', @retval OUTPUT;
```

Under the hood, sp_executesql will execute your SQL and bind the result to your variable and returns the value.