Assign values to a variable from String SQL Query with in a stored procedure
I have an existing stored procedure which takes the Source and Target table names as a Varchar argument and does some complex logics. My requirement is to use the Source table's column1 and with that value build a concatenated output. Ex.,
TableA
Column1
--------
090912
899823
687678

I am taking only the first 2 digits and concatenating it to create an output like, '09,89,68'. This is used for other calculation.
@AllCode being a varchar(max) variable, I added the below select statement which works fine, if the table name is directly given. Now, I am trying to replace the TableA with the input argument which is a varchar. If I use a variable, then I should use the Exec statement. This is where I am struggling to include the @allCode variable assignment.
The is line works fine with actual table name:
select @AllCode = @AllCode + ' ' + Code 
from 
    (select distinct left(Column1,2) as Code 
     from TableA 
     where TableA.Processedflag is null) tmp

print @AllCode --> 09,89,68

I wrote the below code. assigned the subquery from the above line and added it to the @SqlQuery variable. I am not sure how to extend this query and use the Exec to include the @AllCode variable assignment.
alter procedure temp.spSample
    @SrcTbl varchar(100),
    @TgtTbl varchar(100)
as
begin
    declare @AllCode varchar(500);
    declare @SqlQuery varchar(max);

    set @SqlQuery = 'select distinct left(Column1,2) as Code from ' + @SrcTbl + ' where ' + @SrcTbl  +'.ProcessedFlag is null';

    exec(@SqlQuery);
end

How to achieve the above without a table variable? I cannot use a table variable as it is required to be created outside of the stored procedure.
I tried this with having a table variable and storing the values in the table variable. But, in the same stored procedure, I am not able to use the CREATE table variable and using the table variable in the same procedure. I get a table not found issue. It will work fine if the table is created outside, but I don't want to create it outside due to maintenance issue.
Any suggestion, how can I get the concatenated values @allCode as said in the above example? Can it be done without a table variable?

That code is dangerous; it is wise open to SQL injection attacks.

You can pass a table variable to the SP that is populated, create your own custom type.  Or just create a temp table (need to keep connection the same to keep it active) or create a permeant temp table (where you create at at beginning of your long process, then drop it when done, or just keep it with name like StageTableDoStuff, then truncate it every time before you use it.

This is probably one of those X & Y questions, but you can use SP_EXECUTESQL to bind variable to some dynamic sql and get the value out. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75974596/how-the-output-variable-is-working-without-declaring-it/75975618#75975618 for some examples

Your question is not all clear, I'm pretty sure there was a better approach for the whole issue, but you might try this:
General hints:

Better use CONCAT then +. This works better with various types and NULLs.
Do not use SELECT @var = @var + ... for string aggregation. There are some strange side effects.
Use QUOTENAME(). This helps against SQL injection.

--create the test scenario
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dummyTbl;
GO
CREATE TABLE dummyTbl(TheColumn VARCHAR(10), ProcessedFlag BIT);
GO
INSERT INTO dummyTbl VALUES ('090912',1)
                           ,('899823',0)
                           ,('123456',1)
                           ,('654321',0)
                           ,('687678',0);
GO

--That is the best way to aggregate string values
DECLARE @allCodes VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG(LEFT(t.TheColumn,2),',')
    FROM dummyTbl t
    WHERE t.ProcessedFlag=0
);
PRINT @allCodes;
GO

--A trick using JSON in between to allow for varialbe column name (but not for the table's name)
DECLARE @columnName VARCHAR(100)='TheColumn';
DECLARE @allCodes VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG(LEFT(TheValue.OfColumn,2),',')
    FROM dummyTbl t
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT JSON_VALUE((SELECT t.* FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER),CONCAT('$.',@columnName))) TheValue(OfColumn)
    WHERE t.ProcessedFlag=0
);
PRINT @allCodes;
GO

--Fully dynamic approach to retrieve the values from variable table and column
--Important: Use QUOTENAME() around your sysnames. This helps to avoid SQL injection.
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(100)='dummyTbl';
DECLARE @columnName VARCHAR(100)='TheColumn';
DECLARE @allCodes VARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)=CONCAT
(
N'SELECT @allCodes=STRING_AGG(LEFT(t.',QUOTENAME(@columnName),',2),'','')
  FROM ',QUOTENAME(@tableName),' t
  WHERE t.ProcessedFlag=0;'
);
--This will execute the dynamic statement and *output* the assigned variable
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@allCodes VARCHAR(MAX) OUT', @allCodes OUTPUT;
PRINT @allCodes;
GO

--Cleaning
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dummyTbl;
GO

As the result you will see three times the same printed chain of values.
